# ELSE statement doesn't return if while loop returns empty

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

I'm working on a script that checks to see if an email exists in the database `barn_users`, in order to reset a password. And if the email doesn't exists, the token/code is not generated and stored in the database. Everything works perfectly, until I enter an email that is not in the system. The else statement with the error "Could not find email in the system.", doesn't trigger. What am I doing wrong to not get that?

```
    $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE email='$email'";
    $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM barn_users WHERE email='$email'";

    $generate = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_1);
    $searchEmail = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_2);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchEmail)) {
            if(mysqli_num_rows($searchEmail) > 0) {
                if (mysqli_num_rows($generate) > 1) {
            } else if (mysqli_num_rows($generate) < 1) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO password_reset (code,email) VALUES ('$code','$email')";
            } else {
                $sql = "UPDATE password_reset SET code='$code' WHERE email='$email'";
            }   
            if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
                echo "Reset password has been emailed to you"; 
            } else {

            }
        } else {
            echo "Could not find email in the system.";
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Your else is inside your while loop. Will only validate that else if a row is returned.

Comment: I see. Would I be able to escape the loop to return the message?

Comment: What @Bleach said.  Before your while, set a variable - $found - to false.  and in your while before the first if set it to true.  Take off the else "can't find" and have a check on $found after the end of the while.

Comment: @ivanivan That worked! Thank you for the logic on that one. My brain thanks you.

Comment: Just to be clear. Based on the title of your question. Else is not a subfunction of "while".  It is a sub function of of your first "if".  @ivanivan's comment will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @Bleach and @ivanivan for your comments. Both your answers helped out. Here's the working result. Making a variable false outside of the loop, gave me the answer I was looking for.

```
    $sql_1 = "SELECT * FROM password_reset WHERE email='$email'";
    $sql_2 = "SELECT * FROM barn_users WHERE email='$email'";

    $generate = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_1);
    $searchEmail = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_2);

    $found = false;

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($searchEmail)) {
        $found = true;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($searchEmail) > 0) {
            if (mysqli_num_rows($generate) > 1) {

            } else if (mysqli_num_rows($generate) < 1) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO password_reset (code,email) VALUES ('$code','$email')";
            } else {
                $sql = "UPDATE password_reset SET code='$code' WHERE email='$email'";
            }   
            if ($conn->query($sql) == TRUE) {
                echo "Reset password has been emailed to you"; 
            } else {

            }
        } else {

        }
    }

    if ($found == false) {
        echo "Sorry, that email was not found in the system. Please try again.";
    }
```